# How to remove help text and label from django_filters

Tags: django, label, django-filters

I've been trying to remove the help text and label from my filter, How can I do it?

[image]

filters.py

import  django_filters
from oportunity.models import *

```
class BlogFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Oportunity
        fields = {'title': ['contains'],}
```

html

```
 {% load static %}
 {% load crispy_tags_forms %}
 <div class="row">                
        <div class="mt40 mb20">
            <form method="get">
                <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width: 300px;">

                    {{ filter.form|crispy  }}
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use  {{ form.fieldname }}

Comment: thanks Atul Kumar but did not work, if I put field name my form does not show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add **`FILTERS_DISABLE_HELP_TEXT = True`**  to your `settings.py` file

**Reference**
[**`FILTERS_DISABLE_HELP_TEXT`** (official-doc)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/settings.html?highlight=help%20text#filters-disable-help-text)

> Default: `False`
>
> Some filters provide informational `help_text`. For example, csv-based
>   filters (**`filters.BaseCSVFilter`**) inform users that “Multiple values may
>   be separated by commas”.
>
> You may set this to **`True`** to **disable the help_text for all filters**,
>   removing the text from the rendered form’s output.

Comment: easiest way  that I find is to use jquery  to do that, but I would like to use django_filters configuration to remove it .